# Comparing names in two columns in SQL Server and finding the difference

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I need to find new entries added to the column. Suppose I have a column with names:

```
Column_A

John
Paul
Smith
Adam
```

Now after a month I have new names added to the column.

```
Column_A

Adam
Smith
John
Sarah
Paul
Josh
```

The new values can be in any order.

How can we efficiently get the new names added to the column by comparing with the old values in SQL Server(Azure)?

I was thinking about `CASE-WHEN-THEN` expression but, I am not convinced fully.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `except`...

Comment: Although you would be better off adding a date column and tracking when you add the new rows so you can easily identify which ones have changed

Comment: An alternative would be an `NOT EXISTS`. Though I agree with @DaleK , if knowing what's new is important then you should add something to the table to denote it is new; a column that tells you when it was `INSERT`ed is a great way of doing this.